# GCP | How can I provide folder level access to different users>

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

> I have one google bucket gs://kd-non-prod-test/ bucket and 3 service
>   account users

`bucket-poc-user-1@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

`bucket-poc-user-2@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

`bucket-poc-user-3@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

> In bucket i have created 3 directories

```
 - gs://kd-non-prod-test/for-user1 
 - gs://kd-non-prod-test/for-user2
 - gs://kd-non-prod-test/for-user3
```

I want to provide READ,WRITE & LIST access to directories to their respective users.

> Example -

Only *bucket-poc-user-1@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com* user will have READ,WRITE & LIST on only *gs://kd-non-prod-test/for-user1* directory.

> Objects getting stored / updated to respective directory shall have
>   same access as that of directory
>
> Example

if admin user creates text file inside `gs://kd-non-prod-test/for-user1/sample.txt` directory 
then bucket-poc-user-1@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com should also have same access on `gs://kd-non-prod-test/for-user1/sample.txt` as that of directory `gs://kd-non-prod-test/for-user1/`

Help me with solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can give permissions to the entire project or entire bucket. Take a look at [Cloud IAM Roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles). It specifies that `... These roles can be applied either to entire projects or specific buckets.`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Andrei you can't give permission on folders inside a bucket.

If you really want to split permissions between users "folder" you should directly create bucket as "folders" where you give permission to specific users.

Should give you something like this:

```
- gs://for-user1-test
- gs://for-user2-test
- gs://for-user3-test
```

If you want to have an admin having access to all the gcs, you should give him the storage admin roles so that he can access and read any of the buckets.

But I'm don't know if this is really an usable solution as you would end with as many bucket as you have user and if you have hundreds, it may become difficult.